# sequelize update transaction lock row

Tags: postgresql, express, transactions, sql-update, sequelize.js

hello I am trying to create a queue for when someone hits an api route that's is doing an update using sequelize.js on my postgres db. My main goal is to prevent concurrent modification of a row of data.

```
addFile(req, res) {
    // repoPath = directory being watched
    // localPath = full local path change was made on
    const { repoPath, localPath, data, className, lessonName, lessonId, classCode } = req.body;
    const { pathToRepoStorage, subPath, fileDirectory } = this.pathMaker(repoPath, localPath, className, lessonName);
    let repo = null;
    return sequelize.transaction((t) => {
      // chain all your queries here. make sure you return them.
      return Lesson.findById(lessonId,
        {
          transaction: t,
        })
      .then((lesson) => {
        repo = lesson.get('repo');
        this.addNodeToTree(repo, fileDirectory, subPath);
        return Lesson.update({ repo },
          {
            where: {
              id: lessonId,
            },
            transaction: t,
          });
      });
    }).then((updated) => {
      // Transaction has been committed
      // result is whatever the result of the promise chain returned to the transaction callback
      if (updated) {
        fs.outputFile(pathToRepoStorage, data, (err) => {
          if (err) {
            res.sendStatus(500);
          } else {
            // send repo object
            this.io.to(classCode).emit('updated-directory', repo);
            res.sendStatus(200);
          }
        });
      } else {
        throw new Error();
      }
    }).catch((err) => {
      // Transaction has been rolled back
      // err is whatever rejected the promise chain returned to the transaction callback
      res.sendStatus(500);
    });
}
```

the message I'm getting back is:

> 1 Executing (default): UPDATE "lessons" SET
>   "fileWatched"='/Users/Joshua/Desktop/projects/test_watching',"updatedAt"='2017-02-21
>   03:51:23.132 +00:00' WHERE "id" = '5'
>
> 1 Executing (7d3b44c1-022d-45b5-a873-d09be8726963): START
>   TRANSACTION;
>
> 1 Executing (2acc13f0-f351-4c73-b2ee-db1a63c7c460): START
>   TRANSACTION;
>
> 1 Executing (7d3b44c1-022d-45b5-a873-d09be8726963): SET SESSION
>   TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
>
> 1 Executing (2acc13f0-f351-4c73-b2ee-db1a63c7c460): SET SESSION
>   TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
>
> 1 Executing (7d3b44c1-022d-45b5-a873-d09be8726963): SELECT "id",
>   "name", "lecture", "link", "repo", "fileWatched", "createdAt",
>   "updatedAt", "classId" FROM "lessons" AS "lesson" WHERE "lesson"."id"
>   = '5';
>
> 1 Executing (2acc13f0-f351-4c73-b2ee-db1a63c7c460): SELECT "id",
>   "name", "lecture", "link", "repo", "fileWatched", "createdAt",
>   "updatedAt", "classId" FROM "lessons" AS "lesson" WHERE "lesson"."id"
>   = '5';
>
> 1 Executing (7d3b44c1-022d-45b5-a873-d09be8726963): UPDATE "lessons"
>   SET
>   "repo"='[{"title":"hahaha","path":"hahaha"}]',"updatedAt"='2017-02-21
>   03:51:23.189 +00:00' WHERE "id" = '5'
>
> 1 Executing (2acc13f0-f351-4c73-b2ee-db1a63c7c460): UPDATE "lessons"
>   SET
>   "repo"='[{"title":"hello","path":"hello"}]',"updatedAt"='2017-02-21
>   03:51:23.189 +00:00' WHERE "id" = '5'
>
> 1 Executing (7d3b44c1-022d-45b5-a873-d09be8726963): COMMIT;
>
> 1 Executing (2acc13f0-f351-4c73-b2ee-db1a63c7c460): ROLLBACK;

although this does prevent my second call from overriding my first call my second call is completely ignored and I need it to be ran as soon as my first call is done.

This is my very first time messing with transactions and i can't seem to find very good documentation on it what has helped me out the most is
[transaction documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/docs/transactions/#managed-transaction-auto-callback)

Answer (score 1):

Need to set SERIALIZABLE Isolation to prevent this

Ref : http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/api/transaction/

```
return sequelize.transaction({
  isolationLevel: Sequelize.Transaction.SERIALIZABLE
}, function (t) {

 // your transactions

}).then(function(result) {
  // transaction has been committed. Do something after the commit if required.
}).catch(function(err) {
  // do something with the err.
});
```

Comment: so I've tried all 3 ISOLATION_LEVELS.  
Default 'REPEATABLE_READ' first one passes second one gets rolled back.
'READ UNCOMMITTED' they both get committed but the second one overrides the first
'READ COMMITTED' same as read uncommitted
'SERIALIZABLE' same as repeatable read

Answer (score -2):

Please read the link http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/transaction.js~Transaction.html you will be solved the problem

```
return sequelize.transaction({isolationLevel: Sequelize.Transaction.ISOLATION_LEVELS.SERIALIZABLE}, transaction => {

 // your transactions

}).then(result => {
  // transaction has been committed. Do something after the commit if required.
}).catch(err => {
  // do something with the err.
});
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)